# Get user id with request.POST.get works, but value seems to be no integer

Tags: django

I have a simple HTML template

```
<form action="{% url reassign %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<select name="orev">
  {% for rev in rev_list %}
    <option value="{{ rev.id }}">{{rev.id}}:{{ rev.user }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
</form>
```

which shows all users in a specific database. In the corresponding `views.py` I want to operate with the user id that was chosen in the dropdown box.

```
def reassign(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        orev = request.POST.get("orev")
        messages.success(request, _('orev is %(id)s') % {'id': orev})
    #...
```

After submitting a form, the message says (e.g.) "orev is 9". However, it seems like this 9 isn't an integer because I can't compare the value with another integer value.

For example

```
if orev < 100:
    messages.success(request, _('test'))
```

wouldn't write "test", although all user ids are below 100. Do you know where the mistake is?

Thank you!

Comment: convert it to integer by `int(orev)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. Its not an integer, its a string. You need to convert it:

```
try:
   orev_val = int(orev)
except ValueError:
   raise Http500 # Or do something

if orev_val < 100:
   # do stff
```

Comment: did you mean ``raise Http500`` ?